# AMP-MFAH-M Replacement Media Filter for AHMAC - Merv 11

Tags: air-filter

Said [filters are large and more expensive](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MZWOOYJ).  What is the advantage of this class of filter?

Answer (score 1):

The quality of the filter ie the size of the particles it will trap.

The smaller the size the better the filter - of course a coarse filter can be suitable for the task, that depends on what needs to be achieved.

Hepa filters or pollen filters tend to be most expensive.